# Magento 2.2: MiBPHP Fatal error: Interface 'Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface' not found

Tags: magento2, csrf

i am getting error on m2.2 at the time of de validation

```
ch328094@lxv94:~/web/rrrr.com/public_html$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 66.5 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface' not found in /home/ch328094/web/444.com/public_html/app/code/Goomento/Base/Controller/AbstractApiController.php on line 22
```

My is code:

```
abstract class AbstractApiController extends AbstractController implements \Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonResultFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonResultFactory = self::instanceGet(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory::class);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        /** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');

        return new InvalidRequestException(
            $resultRedirect,
            [new Phrase('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.')]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @param int $code
     * @return Json
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Response
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Response
     */
    public function response($data = [], $code = \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::STATUS_CODE_200)
    {
        $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
        $result->setData($data);
        $result->setHttpResponseCode($code);
        $result->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return Json
     */
    public function responseError($data = [])
    {
        return $this->response($this->parseData($data), \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::STATUS_CODE_403);
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @return Json
     */
    public function responseOk($data)
    {
        return $this->response($this->parseData($data));
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array|string|string[]
     */
    protected function parseData($data = [])
    {
        /** To void string translator */
        if ($data == @(string)$data) {
            $data = ['message' => $data];
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands in sequence-

```
rm -rf var/ generated/
php bin/magento se:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```